# Query con inner join y operador LIKE

Tags: sql-server, sql, select, join

Tengo las siguientes tablas con sus respectivos datos

Tabla1

```
+----------+------------+
| IdTabla1 | Velocidad1 |
+----------+------------+
|     1    |   123.51   |
|     2    |   123.55   |
|     3    |   125.23   |
|     4    |   125.87   |
|     5    |   123.50   |
+----------+------------+
```

Tabla2

```
+----------+------------+--------+
| IdTabla2 | Velocidad2 | Estado |
+----------+------------+--------+
|    1     |   123.51   |    M   |
|    2     |   224.55   |    L   |
|    3     |  1245.55   |    I   |
|    4     |   125.87   |    U   |
|    5     |   123.58   |    M   |
+----------+------------+--------+
```

Como puedo hacer para obtener las velocidades **de ambas tablas** que empiecen por ejemplo con: '123.5' ?

```
SELECT ta.[Velocidad1], tb.[Estado]
FROM [dbo].[Tabla1] ta 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Tabla2] lb 
ON  ta.[Velocidad1] = tb.[Velocidad2] OR ta LIKE CONCAT('%123.5%');
```

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato es `Velocidad`?

Comment: @Devid, creo que es una buena idea que, dados los datos de ejemplo, incluyas una tabla con los resultados exactos que buscas encontrar. Ya sabes, una _tabla_ vale más que mil palabras...

Comment: También estaría adecuado un ejemplo de entrada y un resultado esperado. No queda muy claro si lo que necesitas es una join o una union entre las tablas...

Answer (score 2):

la idea es que tu la interpretes mi sugerencia seria asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT ta.IdTabla1 as Id,ta.Velocidad1,tb.Velocidad2, tb.Estado
FROM Tabla1 ta 
INNER JOIN Tabla2 tb 
ON  ta.IdTabla1 = tb.IdtTabla2 WHERE ta.Velocidad1 LIKE '%123.5%' OR tb.Velocidad2 LIKE '%123.5%'
```

Comment: Que agradable respuesta, pero lo que quiero es mostrar son todas las velocidades de ambas tablas que comienze por al algun patron por ejemplo: '123.5'.

Comment: ahí esta saluditos ...
WHERE ta.Velocidad1 LIKE '%123.5%' OR tb.Velocidad2 LIKE '%123.5%'

Answer (score 1):

- Si te aseguras que las 2 tablas te devuelvan la misma cantidad de columnas con el mismo nombre estas puedes simplemente utilizar [`Union`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) es decir haces las 2 consultas y juntas los resultados:

  ```
  SELECT IdTabla1 AS IdTabla,
        Velocidad1 AS Velocidad
  FROM Tabla1 
  WHERE Velocidad LIKE '125,5'

  UNION

  SELECT IdTabla2 AS IdTabla,
        Velocidad2 AS Velocidad
  FROM Tabla2
  WHERE Velocidad LIKE '125,5'
  ```

---

- Tambien puedes introducir los valores que quieres buscar en una tabla temporal para de esta forma no tener que escribir 2 veces los valores:

  ```
  -- Creas una tabla temporal
  DECLARE @valores TABLE (valor int);
  -- introdcues los valores a buscar
  INSERT INTO @valores VALUES(125.5), (80), (122);

  SELECT IdTabla1 AS IdTabla,
         Velocidad1 AS Velocidad
  FROM Tabla1 
  WHERE Velocidad IN @valores

  UNION

  SELECT IdTabla2 AS IdTabla,
        Velocidad2 AS Velocidad
  FROM Tabla2
  WHERE Velocidad IN @valores
  ```

---

- O de por si hacer la union y utlizarlo como una subconsulta:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT IdTabla1 AS IdTabla,
        Velocidad1 AS Velocidad
     FROM Tabla1 

     UNION 

     SELECT IdTabla2 AS IdTabla,
        Velocidad2 AS Velocidad
     FROM Tabla2) AS unidos
  WHERE velocidad LIKE '225.5'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo puedes probar el siguiente query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.IdTabla1, T1.Velocidad1, T2.IdTabla2, T2.Velocidad2, T2.Estado
FROM Tabla1 AS T1, Tabla2 AS T2
WHERE T1.Velocidad1 LIKE '%123.5%' 
AND T2.Velocidad2 LIKE '%123.5%'
```

Lo que note de este query es que te muestra por parejas de resultados. Digamos para comparar entre las 2 tablas donde se cumple la condicion y con que ID, si no es lo que quieres puedes utilizar **UNION** y unir los dos **SELECT** como te indican en las respuestas anteriores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT T1.IdTabla1 AS ID, T1.Velocidad1 AS VELOCIDAD
FROM Tabla1 AS T1
WHERE T1.Velocidad1 LIKE '%123.5%'
UNION
SELECT T2.IdTabla2 AS ID, T2.Velocidad2 AS VELOCIDAD
FROM Tabla2 AS T2
WHERE T2.Velocidad2 LIKE '%123.5%'
```

Espero te funcione y me comentas.